# Scala add element to Nil list in scala

Tags: scala

I'm solving a problem on leetcode- 
https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-absolute-difference/

I can't seem to understand why in the code below the result list is not correctly appended after resetting it to nil.
I looked online of course but could not fathom the concept behind this behavior. Can someone explain why after result is assigned Nil, no value can get added to that list? How do I reset the list? 
I tried with `ListBuffer` and `clear()` but I got the same issue, at the end of the run the result is Nil

Expected behavior:
Input: `arr = [4,2,1,3]`
Output: `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]`

Actual behavior:
Input: `arr = [4,2,1,3]`
Output: `List()`

```
  def minimumAbsDifference(arr: Array[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
    val sortedInput = arr.sorted
    var min = Integer.MAX_VALUE
    var result = Seq[List[Int]]()
    for(i <- 0 until sortedInput.length - 1){
      val diff = sortedInput(i+1) - sortedInput(i)
      if(min > diff){
         result = Nil
         min = diff
      }
      if(min == diff){
        result :+ List(sortedInput(i),sortedInput(i+1))
      }
    }
    result.toList
  }
```

Comment: Inefficient one-liner, just for fun. :) `collection.SortedMap(arr.toList.combinations(2).toList.groupBy { case List(a, b) => math.abs(a - b).toInt }.toSeq: _*).head._2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning `Nil` to `result` and then never assigning anything else.

Because `List` is immutable `result :+ List(...)` returns a new list which is then thrown away.  You need to assign the new list to `result`.

A couple of other notes:

- It is extremely inefficient (decidedly not "leet") to append to a list.  It's much more efficient to prepend (building the result in reverse) and then reverse at the end.
- It is also extremely inefficient to access `List` items by index.
- Use of `var` should generally be avoided in Scala, though this particular usage (contained locally to an otherwise pure function) is not beyond the pale.

Comment: Rather use builder than var, even locally

Comment: @cchantep Can you please elaborate on how to use builder than var, maybe using this example?

Comment: I would suggest not worrying about builders until later in your Scala journey, it's premature optimization.

Comment: Not more premature than using a local `var` for me